# Advantage of linking to genmsg in CMakeLists.txt / package.xml?

Tags: ros, catkin, genmsg, package.xml, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As of now (Nov 26 '12), [rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/Makefile](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/Makefile) page states for `package.xml`:

```
<buildtool_depend>genmsg</buildtool_depend>

This line will have no effect when genmsg exists ouside your workspace, since genmsg is already installed. But for people using your package in the same workspace as genmsg will benefit from this line.
```

In my current particular case, I'm using `genmsg` that resides under `/opt/ros/groovy/share/` so it makes sense if I'm not taking any advantage.

Also for `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(my_pkg)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS rospy genmsg)
```

Without declaring both of above for `genmsg`, I'm able to generate `srv` binding files (in python as I want) by commenting in 2 macros in `CMakeLists.txt` as following:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs)
add_service_files(
  DIRECTORY srv
  FILES
  AddTwoInts.srv
)
generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs  # Or other packages containing msgs
)
```

(I'm working on [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient)).

Question is that is there any advantage of declaring `genmsg` in either/both `package.xml` & `CMakeLists.txt` as above?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49173/advantage-of-linking-to-genmsg-in-cmakelists.txt-/-package.xml?/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2012-11-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the text you posted, I would say yes, there is an advantage. If you or a user of your package boostrap ROS completely from source which means they have rosmsg in their workspace, it will only work if you add the dependency in the package.xml and CMakeLists.txt file. I would consider adding all required dependencies for all possible cases good practice.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What Lorenz says is right, to answer in a different way:
It is always a bug to not declare a dependency, even if on your system, it is not needed. A package should be compilable on all systems, not just your system.

The reason why you do not need the dependency in your CMakeLists,txt is because catkin merges all workspace projects into one. so if one project inyour workspace calls find_package(genmsg), all workspace projects (configured after this project), will also have access to genmsg.

Some may consider this a design flaw in catkin, because people may forget to declare such dependencies because of that.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-11-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3